# Getting all nil properties of UITableViewCell in iOS 10.0

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios10

I get the cell with all property nil in iOS 10 but it was working in iOS 9.0. I just took a cell with custom class and I registered the cell in viewDidLoad and using it in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

viewDidLoad

`[self.tblVw registerClass:[TaskListCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"TaskassignmentCellForStaff"];`

cellForRowAtIndexPath

`TaskListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TaskassignmentCellForStaff" forIndexPath:indexPath];`

Can any one tell me what should be the reason.

Thanks.

Comment: Yep, some code here could help...

Comment: If you are using Storyboard then no need to `registerCell`.

Comment: Do you use storyboard or XIB?

Comment: @dipenPanchasara I was not declaring it before but in iOS 10 app get crash if i did not register the Cell. And yes I am using storyboard

Comment: Do you use custom cell with xib?

Comment: No buddy I took cell in tableview and assigned a class to it.

Comment: I already mentioned code in question. Please look into that.

Comment: NSLog(cell) in cellForRowAtIndexPath.let me know if it's nil

Comment: @dipenPanchasara If I removed registerClass method and run in iOS 9.0 it works fine. But it is crashing in iOS 10.0 then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dipen Panchasara said, If you are using Storyboard then no need to registerCell.

1) I made a new app from scratch.

2) create class TaskListCell

3) create a TVC TaskListController
4) NO need to register

5) I simply wrote:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    TaskListCell * cell = (TaskListCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                                           @"TaskassignmentCellForStaff"
                                                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

ps code is here as a Zip.. feel free to contact me.

Xcode 8.0 beta 6